# What is the speedup? Can't understand the solution

Tags: cpu-architecture

I'm going through a Computer Architecture MOOC on my time. There is a problem I can't solve. The solution is provided but I can't understand the solution. Can someone help me out. Here is the problem and the solution to it:

> Consider an unpipelined processor. Assume that it has 1-ns clock cycle
>   and that it uses 4 cycles for ALU operations and 5 cycles for branches
>   and 4 cycles for memory operations. Assume that the relative
>   frequencies of these operations are 50 %, 35 % and 15 % respectively.
>
> Suppose that due to clock skew and set up, pipelining the processor
>   adds 0.15 ns of overhead to the clock. Ignoring any latency impact,
>   how much speed up in the instruction execution rate will we gain from
>   a pipeline?

Solution

> The average instruction execution time on an unpipelined processor is
>   clockcycle * Avg:CP I = 1ns * ((0.5 * 4) + (0.35 * 5) + (0.15 * 4)) =
>   4.35ns The avg. instruction execution time on pipelined processor is = 1ns + 0.15ns = 1.15ns So speed up = 4.35 / 1.15 = 3.78

My question:

Where is 0.15 coming from in the average instruction execution time on a pipelines processor? Can anyone explain.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the question says those 0.15ns are due to clock skew and pipeline setup.
Forget about pipeline setup and imagine that all of the 0.15ns are from [clock skew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew).

Comment: It's not obvious that the *entire* .15 ns clock skew + setup should be added to the time per instruction.  That gives a qualitative change from exactly 1 instruction per cycle (perfect pipelining) to less than 1 IPC, but apparently we're still ignoring latency?  Why should it matter if the clock signal takes some time to propagate?  If you arrange clock distribution to early stages see the clock edges sooner than later stages, that gives each pipeline stage just over 1ns to do its work.  We're already not considering latency or stalls so writing the register file even later doesn't matter(?)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution implies the CPI (Cycle Per Instruction) is one (1) (w/o the overhead), i.e., 1-ns clock cycle which I'm assuming it's the CPU running clock (1 GHz).

However, I'm not seeing anywhere the CPI is clearly identified as one (1).

Did I misunderstand anything here?

Comment: Agreed, the question seems under-specified.  And it's not clear whether the solution implies the pipelined version has to clock slower, or whether the skew + setup is reducing the IPC to less than exactly 1.  Clock *skew* alone doesn't change the clock frequency, but making the pipeline still work even though there is skew could require clocking lower I guess.  (So results are ready for forwarding soon enough.  Even though the question said to ignore latency effects...)